# Tool to automatically convert handle into bib entry

Tags: bibliographies, tools, convert

There are on-line tools e.g., to [convert isbn into a bib entry](https://www.bibtex.com/c/isbn-to-bibtex-converter/), or [from doi to bib entry](https://www.doi2bib.org/).

I could not find any tool (on-line or off-line) to convert automatically http://hdl.handle.net/ links into bib. entries.

Am I missing something? (*An example of the actual output of such a identifier is http://hdl.handle.net/11366/1987*).